# Outlook 2010 messages pane

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

How do you hide or show the messages pane in Outlook 2010? The messages pane is the pane between the navigation pane and the reading pane which lists all the emails based on your selection from the navigation pane.

Every now and again the messages pane disappears, and I can only see the navigation, reading, and todo panes.

Restarting the computer doesn't bring it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to start Outlook in safe mode by running *outlook.exe /safe* command or holding CTRL keyboard button while clicking Outlook shortcut.
2. Try to reset current view using *View -> View Settings -> Reset Current View*.